# Python 3.x: Creating Patterns with 2D Lists and For Loops

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array, range

For homework, I'm trying to create a pattern in a two-dimensional Python list but the part below (near end) about the right diagonal section doesn't work. I am trying to put "*" at [0][9] then [1][8], [2][7]...etc...[9][0]. I'm confused that left diagonal works but right does not?

Also my code seems messy - is there a way to nest all the for loops together or a better way to go about the task?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#Left, pattern I'm supposed to make. Right, what my code currently does.
*---*---*              *---*----    
-*--*--*-              -*--*----
--*-*-*--              --*-*----
*********              *********
--*-*-*--              ----*-*--
-*--*--*-              ----*--*-
*---*---*              ----*---*


n = 9
#but could be any odd number

lst  = [["-" for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
#create matrix

for i in range(n): #makes left diagonal
    lst[i][i] = "*"

for i in range(n): #middle horizontal section
    lst[n//2][i] = "*"

for i in range(n):
    lst[i][n//2] = "*" #middle vertical section

#for i in range(n, 0, -1): #one of many attempt at right diagonal section
  #  lst[i][i]= "*" #tried changing indexes and/or range but neither worked

for i in lst:
    print(*i) #pattern output
```

Comment: Can you also post the problem statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine (in place of your commented lines):

```
for i in range(n):
    lst[n-i-1][i]= "*"
```

What this code does is to go backwards on the first array index, and forwards on the second. -1 is for avoiding starting from index n which would be out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks, this code and the explanation are very helpful. I'd tried n-i and n-1 but didn't think of n-i-1!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try something like this? Just have everything in one loop instead of having several?

```
for i in range(n):
    lst[i][i] = "*"
    lst[n//2][i] = "*"
    lst[i][n//2] = "*"
    lst[i][n-i-1] = "*"
```